# Blazor WASM - JavaScript not supported on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, blazor, webassembly, .net-8.0

I'm facing the issue when publish blazor app on linux server.

**Problem:**

```
dotnet ProjectName.dll
```

When I'm runing above command, below message is display
[Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKQTR.png)

**Context:**
Server: Ubuntu 22.04 on virtual machine
App: Blazor WASM on .Net 8 with additional API project runing as seperate linux service to communicate
Release command:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64 --self-contained
```

I didn't find any reasonable workaround or even reason problem occur. I'm totally confused about "JS is not supported on linux" cuz JS is working in browser...

I will appreciate any suggestions how can i resolve it.

Comment: I'm running it ons erver but in error message path is windows C disk.... i'm totally confused..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by making blazor wasm hosted by ASP. (there is non option to do that with project creation on .net 8, need to be done manually)

**How i did it?**
Create . net 7 blazor wasm with ASP hosted checkbox On, solution. Upgrade all projects to .net 8, update nugets etc and .net 8 blazor wasm ASP hosted is working as well

Other way is: [Change .net 8 wasm project to ASP Hosted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Ur79_kHVpo&t=602s&ab_channel=PatrickGod)